# Multiply 3×3 matrices: 1) Problems with passing a sub-array to a function and 2) returning the result of the multiplication to ‘main’

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

I am practicing my skills in *C* and now plan to multiply two 3×3 matrices. However, the user can also enter letters, and then as many terms as possible should be offset against each other as well as possible.
Concrete example:
[image: example]

1. Each place is therefore another *unsigned char array*. This means that we are not talking about an unsigned char[][], but rather an unsigned char[][][] per matrix.
   In the function that performs the multiplication of the two 3×3 matrices, it must be checked whether a space contains a letter or a number.

**Now to the problem:** I know, I don't have to pass the complete matrix[][][] to the function `check_whether_there_is_no_letter`, but the last part is enough, ie []. So my specific problem is to understand how I can pass the pointers for such [][][]-ish things. My code works, but I still get warnings:

In the line with this `M1_pure_number[z][s] = check_whether_there_is_no_letter(&(*M1)[z][s]);`, the warning says

> C4048 different declared array subscripts :  "unsigned char (*)[3][3]" and "unsigned char (*)[16]"

The next line, too.

---

**Second problem:** When an unsigned char* is returned, 2 warnings are also displayed. I don't know how to return the result unsigned char[][][]. That's why I provisionally created a string with 144 places (3*3*16).

For this line `strcpy(uStrOut, Results_matrix);`, the warning is:

> C4024 *strcpy* different types for formal and actual parameter 2

> C4047 Function : 'const char*' differs in levels of indirection from 'unsigned char[3][3][16]'

---

**In the main.c**

```
// matrix 1
unsigned char M1[3][3][16] = { '\0' };
        printf("Geben Sie die Zahlen oder Buchstaben ein. Beispiel:\n1\t2\t3\n4\t5\t6\n7\t8\t9\n\n");
        unsigned char buffer1[3] = { '\0' };
        for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
        {
            for (int s = 0; s < 3; s++)
            {
                    scanf("%2s", &buffer1);
                    M1[z][s][0] = buffer1[0];
                    M1[z][s][1] = buffer1[1];
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
        discard_left_over_characters_in_stdins_buffer();

        // matrix 2

        unsigned char M2[3][3][16] = { '\0' };
        printf("Geben Sie die Zahlen oder Buchstaben ein. Beispiel:\n1\t2\t3\n4\t5\t6\n7\t8\t9\n\n");
        unsigned char buffer2[3] = { '\0' };
        for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
        {
            for (int s = 0; s < 3; s++)
            {
                scanf("%2s", &buffer2);
                M2[z][s][0] = buffer2[0];
                M2[z][s][1] = buffer2[1];
            }
        }


        unsigned char* result_of_the_two = multiply_3_x_3_by_3_x_3_matrix(&M1, &M2);
        free(result_of_the_two);
```

**The functions**

```
bool check_whether_there_is_no_letter(unsigned char(*m)[3][3])
{
    if (isdigit(m[0][0][0]) && m[0][0][1] == '\0')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

unsigned char* multiply_3_x_3_by_3_x_3_matrix(unsigned char(*M1)[3][3][16], unsigned char(*M2)[3][3][16])
{
    unsigned char Results_matrix[3][3][16] = { '\0' };
    bool M1_pure_number[3][3] = { false };
    bool M2_pure_number[3][3] = { false };

    // – – – – – – – – – – – – – – – – – –

    // |A   B   C|   |J   K   L|   |A*J+B*M+C*P     A*K+B*N+C*Q     A*L+B*O+C*R|
    // |D   E   F| * |M   N   O| = |D*J+E*M+F*P     D*K+E*N+F*Q     D*L+E*O+F*R|
    // |G   H   İ|   |P   Q   R|   |G*J+H*M+İ*P     G*K+H*N+İ*Q     G*L+H*O+İ*R|

    for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
    {
        for (int s = 0; s < 3; s++)
        {
            M1_pure_number[z][s] = check_whether_there_is_no_letter(&(*M1)[z][s]);
            M2_pure_number[z][s] = check_whether_there_is_no_letter(&(*M2)[z][s]);
        }
    }
    

    // – – – – – – – – – – – – – – – – – –

    unsigned char* uStrOut = (unsigned char*)malloc(144u);
    strcpy(uStrOut, Results_matrix);
    return uStrOut;
}
```

This is a practice project, so I would like to learn how to use it and not integrate any 3rd party Dlls.

I appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: If your symbolic names could be more complex (`a+b` etc), then your terms could expand to be quite large.  My best guess is that you need a 3x3 array of character pointers, and you need to dynamically allocate the string for each cell.  I think you also need code to add and multiply two terms, and to simplify one term.  You may need to add parentheses in the expressions (`3 • (a + b)` rather than `3 • a + b`, for example).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler _and to simplify one term. You may need to add parentheses in the expressions (3 • (a + b) rather than 3 • a + b_ I intend to do that, too. I wanted to solve this problem first.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with.  It uses 3x3 matrices of `char *`, dynamically allocating the strings pointed to by each cell.  It shows how to pass the matrices to functions and so on.  It contains code to read the data and to print the resulting matrices.  It also contains code to calculate the result of multiplying 3x3 matrices.  It would be trivial to extend the code to handle a different size of square matrix.  It would be possible, though not particularly simple, to handle different sizes of matrix at runtime without replicating the code.

I've simplified some of the code by using `char` instead of `unsigned char` (the standard library works on strings of `char`, not `unsigned char`).  I've used some library functions that are available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c`, `stderr.h`, `emalloc.c`, `emalloc.h` and `estrdup.c` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  These simplify the error handling — the memory allocation functions 'never fail' (more accurately, exit the program if memory allocation fails).  This simplifies the code considerably, but isn't necessarily a good strategy for production code.  It is an example of 'fail fast', though.

I used `scanf()` with `%s` to read expressions.  This is convenient; it breaks at spaces.

I've not written code to validate the inputs; GIGO — garbage in, garbage out.  I've not written code to simplify expressions.  Both of those are outside the scope of the question.

```
/* SO 6993-0640: Multiply 3x3 matrices symbolically */

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stderr.h"
#include "emalloc.h"

// SOF - matrix.h
enum { N = 3 };
typedef char *Cell;
typedef Cell Matrix[N][N];

extern void init_matrix(Matrix matrix);
extern void print_matrix(const char *tag, const Matrix matrix);
extern void read_matrix(Matrix matrix);
extern void free_matrix(Matrix matrix);
extern void multiply_matrices(Matrix m1, Matrix m2, Matrix result);
// EOF - matrix.h

void init_matrix(Matrix matrix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = NULL;
    }
}

static void read_cell(int r, int c, Cell *cell)
{
    char buffer[256];
    if (scanf("%s", buffer) != 1)
        err_error("failed to read value for cell[%d,%d]\n", r, c);
    // validate data in cell?
    if (*cell != 0)
        free(*cell);
    *cell = STRDUP(buffer);
}

void read_matrix(Matrix matrix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            read_cell(i, j, &matrix[i][j]);
    }
}

void free_matrix(Matrix matrix)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < N; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < N; c++)
        {
            free(matrix[r][c]);
            matrix[r][c] = NULL;
        }
    }
}

static int max_cell_length(const Matrix matrix)
{
    int maxlen = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < N; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < N; c++)
        {
            if (matrix[r][c] == NULL)
                continue;
            int curlen = strlen((char *)matrix[r][c]);
            if (curlen > maxlen)
                maxlen = curlen;
        }
    }
    return maxlen;
}

void print_matrix(const char *tag, const Matrix matrix)
{
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    int width = max_cell_length(matrix);
    for (int r = 0; r < N; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < N; c++)
        {
            const char *value = matrix[r][c];
            if (value == NULL)
                value = ".";
            printf("    %*s", width, value);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

static Cell multiply_row_by_column(int r, int c, Matrix m1, Matrix m2)
{
    const char *pad = "";
    size_t len = N * sizeof("().()");
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
        len += strlen(m1[r][k]) + strlen(m2[k][c]);
    Cell result = MALLOC(len);
    result[0] = '\0';
    size_t reslen = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
    {
        // Consider analyzing cells here before creating the result
        int nbytes = snprintf(&result[reslen], len - reslen, "%s(%s).(%s)",
                              pad, m1[r][k], m2[k][c]);
        reslen += nbytes;
        pad = "+";
    }
    // result = simplify(result);
    return result;
}

void multiply_matrices(Matrix m1, Matrix m2, Matrix result)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < N; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < N; c++)
        {
            if (result[r][c] != NULL)
                free(result[r][c]);
            result[r][c] = multiply_row_by_column(r, c, m1, m2);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Matrix m1 = { 0 };
    Matrix m2 = { 0 };
    err_setarg0("3x3 Matrix Multiplication");

    read_matrix(m1);
    read_matrix(m2);

    print_matrix("M1", m1);
    print_matrix("M2", m2);

    Matrix m3;
    init_matrix(m3);

    multiply_matrices(m1, m2, m3);
    print_matrix("M1.M2", m3);

    free_matrix(m1);
    free_matrix(m2);
    free_matrix(m3);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are two example outputs — one using the matrix shown in the question, one using an adaptation of that data with more symbolic values:

```
M1:
    ab     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
M2:
    -1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
M1.M2:
    (ab).(-1)+(2).(4)+(3).(7)     (ab).(2)+(2).(5)+(3).(8)     (ab).(3)+(2).(6)+(3).(9)
     (4).(-1)+(5).(4)+(6).(7)      (4).(2)+(5).(5)+(6).(8)      (4).(3)+(5).(6)+(6).(9)
     (7).(-1)+(8).(4)+(9).(7)      (7).(2)+(8).(5)+(9).(8)      (7).(3)+(8).(6)+(9).(9)

M1:
    3ab      2      3
      4    c+d      6
      7      8    e-f
M2:
     -1      2    k-2
      4    k+2      6
    k-1      8      9
M1.M2:
    (3ab).(-1)+(2).(4)+(3).(k-1)     (3ab).(2)+(2).(k+2)+(3).(8)     (3ab).(k-2)+(2).(6)+(3).(9)
    (4).(-1)+(c+d).(4)+(6).(k-1)     (4).(2)+(c+d).(k+2)+(6).(8)     (4).(k-2)+(c+d).(6)+(6).(9)
    (7).(-1)+(8).(4)+(e-f).(k-1)     (7).(2)+(8).(k+2)+(e-f).(8)     (7).(k-2)+(8).(6)+(e-f).(9)
```

An alternative way of handling symbolic and numeric data in the matrix is to create a structure, probably with a `union` and a discriminator value:

```
struct Cell
{
   enum { NUMBER, STRING } type;
   union
   {
       long long  number_value;
       char      *string_value;
   };
};
```

This can be set appropriately as cells are created (`read_cell()` etc) and then exploited when multiplying cells and simplifying results.

You might need to use a different type from `long long` for numbers, such as `double`.